# PHP preg_match country aka letters and spaces

Tags: php, preg-match

I'm looking for a handy way to check for letters and spaces with preg_match in PHP.

So you can only add 'The Netherlands' or 'Denmark'

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add 'The Netherlands' or 'Denmark' to what? What's wrong with a simple substring search or even straight string comparison?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/', $string);
```

`^` and `$` mean, respectively, the beginning and the end of the string, `a-z` are lowercase letters, `A-Z` are uppercase letters, `\s` is whitespace and `+` means 1 or more times.

Comment: `\s` will also allow the 'tab' character. And, of course, we don't know if spaces must (or must not) be at the start or end of the string that is going to be checked, etc..anyway, to me this answer looks good :)

Comment: Isn't the ^ supposed to go inside the bracket, like such preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z\s]+$/', $string);?